# Using Cramer's Rule

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The three equations given are:
\begin{cases}
x+y-z=4 \\
x-2y+3z=-6 \\
2x+3y+z=7
\end{cases}

I am having trouble putting it into the matrix format, which in turn is hindering my ability to solve for the determinant. I am also not sure how to solve for $x$, $y$, and $z$ with Cramer's Rule.

Comment: What troubles are you having?

Comment: It's much faster to put the augmented matrix in *reduced* row echelon form. Do you really have to use Cramer's formulæ?

Comment: Write it like this.
\begin{align*}
x+y-z&=4 \\x-2y+3z&=-6 \\2x+3y+z&=7
\end{align*}
Can you put this in matrix form now?

Comment: @GEdgar How is that any different?

Answer (score 1):

Using the information you provide we get the following equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -1\\
    1 & -2 & 3\\
    2 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 4\\ -6\\ 7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which should be in an easy enough form to use Cramer's rule. Remember that the matrix you get from a system of equations is the matrix of *coefficients* in your equations

Comment: oops typo you're right

Answer (score 1):

We start by writing the equations like so:$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -1\\
    1 & -2 & 3\\
    2 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y\\ z
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 4\\ -6\\ 7
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, let's call the $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ and the vector on the right hand side of the equation $b$. Then, we first observe $$\det(A)=-13.$$ In order to use Cramer's rule, we replace the relevant column with $b$, calling this matrix $A_i$ for $i\in\{x,y,z\}$ and work out the determinant of this new matrix and divide it by $\det(A)$. So, carrying this procedure out gives $$\det(A_x)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 1 & -1\\
    -6 & -2 & 3\\
    7 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=-13,$$ $$\det(A_y)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 4 & -1\\
    1 & -6 & 3\\
    2 & 7 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=-26,$$ $$\det(A_z)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 4\\
    1 & -2 & -6\\
    2 & 3 & 7
\end{pmatrix}=13.$$ This then allows us to conclude $$x=1,\quad y=2,\quad z=-1.$$

However, as Bernard alludes to in the comments, I think you may appreciate at this point that Cramer's rule is quite inefficient and I would suggest using reduced row echelon form to obtain the solution set to these sorts of problems instead.